# Using a Aggregate Function in a Calculated Field

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, aggregate-functions

I have a query that works fine on SQL Server Management Studio, except a int is turned into a float for no reason (I'm not sure if that's important). When I try to run it in Visual Studio 2012 it throws an error about aggregated functions in a calculated field.

I tried so many variations on the query but that fact it works one place and now another when they're both using the same database makes no sense to me.

```
SELECT 
v1.pk,
v1.description,
SUM(v1.quantity)
FROM v1
INNER JOIN v2 ON v1.v1_fk = v2.pk
WHERE v1.v1_fk = 5 AND
    v1.date >= @date AND
    v2.foo = 1 AND
    v1.bar LIKE '%1%'
GROUP BY v1.pk, v1.description
HAVING SUM(v1.quantity) <= @num
ORDER BY pk
```

This works fine in SQL Server Management Studio. In Visual Studio it throws "Definition for report in invalid. Expression for calculated field 'quantity' includes an aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function. These cannot be used in calculated field expressions.

Comment: That error doesn't match the SQL (which is missing a `SELECT`) you have. That error is for if you were trying to do exactly what it says; use an aggregate function for a calculated column. For example, you can't do `ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD TotalQuantity AS SUM(Quantity);`. If you want aggregated result, you're probably after a `VIEW`.

Comment: I accidentally had the SELECT on the same line and the ``` and I'm only using views that have a hard coded Quantity column. I'm not sure why it thinks in a calculated field and why it only has issues in Visual Studio 2012. It's such a basic query could it be a Visual Studio Bug?

Comment: If it was a VS 2012 bug it would have been found years ago; it's 7 years old now. Without a way to replicate the problem we can't really help you here.

Comment: Is there any additional information I can provide to help replicate the problem?

Comment: Show us what you're doing in VS to produce the error.

Comment: While re-created the report in Visual Studio without any sensitive data the issue resolved itself even though I was running the same code with the same parameters. My apologies for wasting your time.